# EXCEL finding consecutive duplicate rows in excel

Tags: excel-formula

in excel one column contains like below
1
2
5
6
1
2
5
6
3
4

### Now i want to find out consecutive 1 2 coming 2 times. 5,6 coming 2 times. 3,4 coming 1 time. Please let me know how this can be achieve.

similarly consecutive 3 duplicates.
1
2
3
7
8
9
1
2
3
7
8
9
3
4
5

Now i want to find out consecutive 1 2 3 coming 2 times. 5,6 coming 2 times. 3,4 coming 1 time. Please let me know how this can be achieve.

Comment: How about 1,2,3,7 in the above sequence? Isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: And how about 1,2,3,7,8,9 in that sequence? Where and how will you specify the criterion of the number of values to be considered as a sequence for being flagged duplicate (i.e., whether the formula should consider 1,2,3 or just 1,2 or 1,2,3,7,8,9)?

Comment: here  want to find the 3 consecutive duplicates. i.e 1 2 3 is coming how many times. 7 8 9  coming how many times.  Thanks sriniwaas +91-9900216423

Comment: Hi Mahesh. Thanks for the reply. here exactly i am copying the  function in 
 C2 =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,D2,$A$3:$A$12,E2). But i am getting zero.

Comment: @sriniwaas, have you filled in the data in column A as shown? It'll be better if you can post a screenshot of your worksheet.

Comment: @sriniwaas, if your doubt is about an answer posted here, add it as a comment to that answer. And use "@" tags. Otherwise, the user won't be notified.

Comment: @sriniwaas.thanks for swift response. here this is new question. question is how to highlight with color to the sequence of numbers in  excel column. i.e

Comment: i.e 1 2 3 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 . Here the sequence is 1 2 3 right. I want this sequence with color in the same column.

Comment: one more example : 1 2 3 4 2 3 3 4 1 4 1 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 Here the sequence is 1 2 3 4 right. I want this sequence with color in the same column.Kindly let me know

Comment: @Mahesh. thank u very much.  this is new question. question is how to highlight with color to the sequence of numbers in excel column..e 1 2 3 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 . Here the sequence is 1 2 3 right. I want this sequence with color in the same column.1 2 3 4 2 3 3 4 1 4 1 3 2 4 1 2 3 4 Here the sequence is 1 2 3 4 right. I want this sequence with color in the same column.Kindly let me know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data from which to count occurrences of sequences is in column A, you can specify the criteria in columns D & E (for sequences of length 2), and then use `COUNTIFS` to achieve the result.

Enter this function in C2 and drag it down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,D2,$A$3:$A$12,E2)
```

This will give you the following result:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══╦═══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║    ║  A   ║ B ║   C   ║     D     ║     E     ║
╠════╬══════╬═══╬═══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ Data ║   ║ Count ║ Element 1 ║ Element 2 ║
║----║------║---║-------║-----------║-----------║
║  2 ║ 1    ║   ║   2   ║     1     ║     2     ║
║  3 ║ 2    ║   ║   2   ║     5     ║     6     ║
║  4 ║ 5    ║   ║   1   ║     3     ║     4     ║
║  5 ║ 6    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
║  6 ║ 1    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
║  7 ║ 2    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
║  8 ║ 5    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
║  9 ║ 6    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
║ 10 ║ 3    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
║ 11 ║ 4    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║
╚════╩══════╩═══╩═══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

If you want to specify more than 2 numbers in the sequence, you'll have to add an extra column, and modify the function to include another criteria pair, like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16,D2,$A$3:$A$17,E2,$A$4:$A$18,F2)
```

**Note:** Cells C3 and C4 still contain the same function as the first one. This modified version is only for criteria where you're looking for sequences of 3 numbers.

The result:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══╦═══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║    ║  A   ║ B ║   C   ║     D     ║     E     ║     F     ║
╠════╬══════╬═══╬═══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ Data ║   ║ Count ║ Element 1 ║ Element 2 ║ Element 3 ║
║----║------║---║-------║-----------║-----------║-----------║
║  2 ║ 1    ║   ║   2   ║     1     ║     2     ║     3     ║
║  3 ║ 2    ║   ║   0   ║     5     ║     6     ║           ║
║  4 ║ 3    ║   ║   1   ║     3     ║     4     ║           ║
║  5 ║ 7    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║  6 ║ 8    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║  7 ║ 9    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║  8 ║ 1    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║  9 ║ 2    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 10 ║ 3    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 11 ║ 7    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 12 ║ 8    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 13 ║ 9    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 14 ║ 3    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 15 ║ 4    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
║ 16 ║ 5    ║   ║       ║           ║           ║           ║
╚════╩══════╩═══╩═══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```